# Sequence Limit Question

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-limit-theorems

Take the sequence of cosine iterates as follows:
$x_0 = π/4$, $x_{n+1} = \cos(x_n)$ for n = 0, 1, 2, . . . .

One can prove that this sequence converges, say to p. Show that (p, cos p) is the point where the graph of y = cos x intersects the
line y = x.

Any hints or pointers?

Comment: This seems like a case for the contraction-mapping theorem.

Comment: @user99680 Sorry i'm not familiar with that theorem, could you elaborate?

Comment: :Sure;  The theorem, a.k.a, Banach fixed-point theorem gives you conditions that guarantee the existence of a fixed point, i.e., a point x with f(x)=x. This is equivalent to intersecting the line $y=x$. A contraction map $f$ is one in which $d(x,y) < d(f(x),f(y))$. The theorem also gives you an explicit formula for the fixed point. See, e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $x_n$ converges to $p$.  By the continuity of $\cos(x)$, we may state
$$
\cos p =
\cos\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n\right) = 
\lim_{n \to \infty}\cos x_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n+1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = p
$$

Comment: oh, okay .... I think i see the correlation here ... that cos(x) = y  thus the point (x, cos(x))

Comment: The curve $y = x$ intersects $y = \cos(x)$ at $x = p$ if and only if $p = \cos(p)$.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes, sorry for being vague and not using the same notation as your answer ... Thanks a lot